# Endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let G be any  abelian group, End(G) be the set of all  group homomorphisms $\varphi\colon G\to G $.

End(G) is a unital ring under the operations + and $\cdot$(Please refer to [the link](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~mathclub/cheat_sheets/notes.150C.pdf) for detail, theorem 1.6.1).

If $G=\Bbb Z/{n\Bbb Z}\oplus\Bbb Z/{n\Bbb Z}$. then,  what is the ring End($G$)?

---

A group homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to G $ is determined by $\varphi(\bar1,\bar0)$ and $\varphi(\bar0,\bar1)$

It seems that End($G$) is isomorphism to $M_2(\Bbb Z/{n\Bbb Z})$, the $2\times 2$ matrix ring over $\Bbb Z/{n\Bbb Z}$

But how to prove this? Thank you very much

Comment: The result seems immediate; what part of it are you stuck on?

Comment: @anomaly  how to prove End(G) is isomorphism to $M_2(\Bbb Z/{n\Bbb Z})$?

Comment: Just imagine that $G$ is a vector space of dimension 2. To any endomorphism $\phi$ associate the matrix whose first column is formed by the coordinates of $\phi (1,0)$ with respect to the basis $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ of $G$.  It should be clear what you have to do obtain the second column.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some steps you can follow:

1. Learn what a module is. Note that it's similar to a vector space.
2. Note that every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, where the action of an integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ on a group element $g$ is just $n\cdot g := \underbrace{(g+g+g+\cdots+g)}_{n \text{ times}}$. Similarly, homomorphisms between abelian groups are the same as $\mathbb{Z}$-linear maps (viewing the abelian groups as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.
3. Prove to yourself that for $n$-dimensional vector spaces $V$ over a field $k$, $k$-linear maps from $V$ to itself are precisely the same as $n\times n$ matrices. Here you will use crucially the fact that every vector space has a basis.
4. Noting that $G := (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ has a basis as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module (the basis is just $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, imitate the proof of (3) to show that $\mathbb{Z}$-linear maps $G\rightarrow G$ are the same as $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.